# Starting Out In LiveWeave

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to make cute little games recently in javascript, using LiveWeave HTML/CSS/javascript playground. However, I can't seem to figure out how to properly insert javascript. What blocks do I use? Could I put the script in the HTML? The reason I'm asking is that I tested it out by making a few rects around the screen, yet none showed up. To help, please go to http://liveweave.com. 
                                                                  Best Regards,
                                                                        Dominic

Comment: Please save your LiveWeave playground. (Button 'save') and post the link (e.g. http://liveweave.com/seT0k6) here. Then we know what we can discuss about, and you will certainly get proper help.